# Считывание данных из файла си

Tags: c

Я не особо понимаю, как работает считывание данных из файла. Например, мне нужно считать из файла, содержащего три цифры, которые записаны через пробел и записать их в переменные внутри программы, как это сделать? Пытался сделать так(не понимаю, что неправильно):

```
FILE* file;
file = fopen("input.txt","r");
int a, b, c;
fscanf(file,"%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);`
```

Comment: Вполне правильно, этот это успешно отрабатывает. Что не так?

Comment: Выскакивает исключение :  Недопустимый параметр был передан функции, для которой недопустимые параметры

Comment: Значит наверное у вас файл input.txt не существует или содержит некорректные данные

Comment: Точно существует, он же просто должен быть на устройстве или нужны какие-то дополнительные манипуляции?

Comment: Он должен быть в текущей рабочей папке, в которой запускается программа

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116763/discussion-between-gleb-kamisaraw-and-andreymal).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стоило бы делать так:

```
file = fopen("input.txt","r");  
if (file == NULL) {
    // обработка ошибки открытия
    }
if (3 != fscanf(file,"%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)) {
    // обработка ошибки чтения
    }
```